# How to connect ethereum node through proxy agent using ethers.js?

Tags: ethers.js, nodejs

I am trying to connect an Ethereum node which is outside of my organisation. So that's why I need to use a proxy agent to connect external URLs.

I am looking for a way to configure the proxy agent while setting up the `ethers.js` provider.

Say my ethereum node is: `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/xxxxxx`
and proxy is `myproxy-network.com:80`.

I already did this using `web3.js` and HttpProvider, which works but have to move with `ethers.js` due to business needs. The web3.js example is shown below -

```js
const tunnel = require('tunnel')
const Web3 = require('web3')

const options = {
    keepAlive: true,
    timeout: 20000,
    agent: {
        https: tunnel.httpsOverHttp({
            proxy: {
                host: 'myproxy-network.com',
                port: 80
            }
        })
    }
}
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/xxxxxx', options))
```

Need help to do something similar with `ethers.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will dissapoint you. Cause there is still no method or option to add custom http agent through the ether.js.

There had been a PR and the developer said he might add it in ethersV5 but surely in ether.js version 6.

I guess you have to wait until the release of v6 before using this function. The current version is 5.6.

PR: [Add support for custom http.agent.](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/2775)

Comment: For now, web3.js is the only way then! Thanks